# execute variable number of mongo queries in node, return single result

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Ooof.  Ever have one of those days where you know you're close, but you just can't quite get it?

I am writing a hangman puzzle solver.  This is running in a service written with node/hapi backended with mongo db.

So I have a function:

```
solvePuzzle(puzzle, alreadyCalled);
```

The args are the puzzle itself, with solved letters as literals, and unsolved as ?s, like so:

```
?O?N? ?O ?H? ?TO??
```

and alreadyCalled being simply a list of letters called but incorrect.  After some mucking about, a RegEx is created for each word, which is then sent to a function that queries a wordlist stored in mongo for matches.

Everything is functioning as it should, and if I create a dummy wordlist as a simple array, everything works fine and I get a list of matches.

The return format is an array of objects like so:  (I use array indices to preserve word order when displaying possible solutions)

```
matches[0][?O?N?] = ['GOING', 'DOING', 'BOING'];
```

So on to the actual PROBLEM.  I split the whole puzzle into words, and run a for loop over them, calling the function which performs the mongo query for each one.  Problem is, that function call seems to be returning before the query has actually run.  The console logs interspersed throughout seem to bear this theory out.

I tried having the query function return a promise, but that has only served to muddy the waters further.  I feel like I'm *close* but yeah - I dunno.  Here was my original non-promise code:

```
function solvePuzzle(puzzle, called) {
    // first build the exclusion match pattern
    //console.log('solvePuzzle: building match pattern');
    var x = buildMatchPattern(puzzle, called);
    // split the puzzle into words
    //console.log('solvePuzzle: tokenizing puzzle');
    var words = tokenize(puzzle.toUpperCase());
    //console.log('solvePuzzle:', words);
    var results = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        console.log('solvePuzzle: matching ' + words[i]);
        results[i] = {};
        results[i][words[i]] = matchWord(words[i], x);
    }
    console.log('solvePuzzle: matches: ', results);
    return results;
}

function matchWord(word, exclude) {
    var pattern = '^';
    var letters = word.toUpperCase().split('');
    var matches = new Array();
    var query = {};

    //console.log('matchWord:', letters);

    for(var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        if(letters[i] !== '?') {
            pattern += letters[i];
        }
        else {
            pattern += exclude;
        }
    }

    pattern += '$';
    var re = new RegExp(pattern);
    //console.log('matchWord:', re);

    query.word = {"$regex" : re, "$options": "i"};
    //console.log("matchWord query:", JSON.stringify(query));
    db.wordlist.find(query, function (err, words) {
        if(err) {
            console.error('error:', err);
        }
        for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if(words[i] !== null) {
                console.log('loop:', words[i].word);
                matches.push(words[i].word);
            }
        }
        console.log('matchWord:', matches.length);
        if(matches.length < 1) {
            console.log('matchWord: found no matches');
            matches.push('No Matches Found');
        }

        return matches;
    });
}
```

So my console output was basically:

```
solvePuzzle: matching ?O?N?
solvePuzzle: matches: []       <---- problem
loop: 'going'
loop: 'doing'
etc etc.
.
.
matchWord: 5   (number of matches found);
```

So as you can see, the call to matchWord is returning before the actual query is running.  So I have never done a hapi service backed by mongo.  How can I structure this code so it loops over all the words, queries mongo for each one, and returns a single array as result?

TIA.

Comment: see my update !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In node, database calls are asynchronous so you can't use `return` like this.
You need to use Promise (native in node.js)

this code should work :

```
function solvePuzzle(puzzle, called) {
        var results = [];
        // first build the exclusion match pattern
        var x = buildMatchPattern(puzzle, called);
        // split the puzzle into words
        var words = tokenize(puzzle.toUpperCase());
        // an array to store the words index 
        var indexes = Array.apply(null, {
            length: words.length
        }).map(Number.call, Number); // looks like [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
        // create a Promise for each word in words
        var promises = indexes.map(function(index) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                console.log('solvePuzzle: matching ' + words[index]);
                results[index] = {};
                var pattern = '^';
                var letters = words[index].toUpperCase().split('');
                var matches = new Array();
                var query = {};

                for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
                    if (letters[i] !== '?') {
                        pattern += letters[i];
                    } else {
                        pattern += exclude;
                    }
                }
                pattern += '$';
                var re = new RegExp(pattern);

                query.word = {
                    "$regex": re,
                    "$options": "i"
                };
                db.wordlist.find(query, function(err, wordsRes) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('error:', err);
                        reject(err); // if request failed, promise doesn't resolve
                    }
                    for (let i = 0; i < wordsRes.length; i++) {
                        if (wordsRes[i] !== null) {
                            console.log('loop:', wordsRes[i].word);
                            matches.push(wordsRes[i].word);
                        }
                    }
                    console.log('matchWord:', matches.length);
                    if (matches.length < 1) {
                        console.log('matchWord: found no matches');
                        matches.push('No Matches Found');
                    }
                    results[index][words[index]] = matches;
                    resolve(); // request successfull
                });
            });
        });
        // when all promise has resolved, then return the results
        Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
            console.log('solvePuzzle: matches: ', results);
            return results;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Sadly, this does not work.  Using the debugger in VS Code, I set a breakpoint on the return results; line in solvePuzzle, and it returns, THEN I see all the matches appear in the console.  So the client (Postman in this case) using "??CK ?Y ?A???" as input gets an array of 3 empty objects as a response.

Comment: Oh I forgot the return of solvePuzzle, my bad. You need to use Promises here, I'll update my answer in a minut

Comment: Took a bit of doing since all that was being called by hapi's route handler, so I was getting a repeat of the problem there.  Solved that one by passing in a callback.  At any rate - thanks for this.  I knew promises were gonna be the solution, I just couldn't figure out exactly how to structure it.